# Multiple alignments

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

If I have a string of equations whose equal signs are aligned and one of the equations is too long and needs to span multiple lines, how do I create a second alignment. For instance, in the following example

```
\begin{align*}  
  f(x)&=eqn1\\  
      &=eqn2_part1+eqn2_part2\\   
      &           +eqn2_part3\\  
      &=eqn3\\   
      &=eqn4\\  
\end{align*}
```

How do I align the equals signs and the plus signs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using boxes via `\phantom` is also an option, if alignment characters like `&&` get in the way for long equations:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}  
  f(x)&=\text{eqn}_1\\  
      &=\text{eqn}_2\text{-part}_1+\text{eqn}_2\text{-part}_2\\   
      &\phantom{{}=\text{eqn}_2\text{-part}_1}{}+\text{eqn}_2\text{-part}_3\\  
      &=\text{eqn}_3\\   
      &=\text{eqn}_4\\  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

A correction for the spacing around binary operators (`{}+`) and relations (`{}=`) is required though. See Herbert's [`mathmode` document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) for more on AMS environments and alignment.

Answer (score 11):

You could use `alignat` which is also from the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  f(x)&=eqn1                    &&   \\  
      &=eqn2_part1              && +eqn2_part2 \\   
      &                         && +eqn2_part3\\  
      &=eqn3                    &&   \\   
      &=eqn4                    &&   \\  
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

You'll notice that the `alignat` environment takes an argument- which is (quoting from the documentation)

> the number of “equation columns”: count the maximum number of &s in
>   any row, add 1 and divide by 2.

Comment: When I compile I get a large gap between eqn2_part1 and the plus signs when the length of eqn3 and 4 are longer than eqn2_part1.

Comment: @richtera perhaps you could add your code to your question so that folks can play with it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try [`breqn`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mh/breqn.pdf) package. Then use `\begin{dmath}...\end{dmath}` environment.
For example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
        g\left[Pr(unrest_{im}=1)\right]=\alpha_{0i}
            +\alpha_{1}.\left|price\_shock_{im}\right|
            +\beta.{year}+\gamma.region.\left|price\_shock_{im}\right|
            +\delta.{region}+\epsilon_{im}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]