# Formatting taxicab numbers

Tags: formatting

Thanks for taking a look at my question.

How can I get this formatting (shown in image)?

[image: Taxicab]

I appreciate your help, this community is great.

Comment: What have you tried? Please post a minimal working example rather than a do-it-for-me image. What about the formatting is the problem? Alignment? Font? Something else?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58150/multiple-alignments/58154#58154

Comment: If this solves your problem then you should thank cmhughes by upvoting:)

Comment: Good idea, @Andrew l, I'll do that now.  :)